# Detection of connection loss/regain in Windows through Java code

Tags: java, http, httpconnection

I have a desktop based Java application with SWT frontend.

In my application i make http calls to my backend.
Now i want to detect the connection loss i.e. to get notified if the connection is lost in my application.

Currently i have the following approach, if any http request fails i reactively detect that as a connection failure. i don't to want to check if connection exist every time before my http request.

Whenever the connection failure happens i start polling at regular intervals to check if the connection is there . If connection is regained i stop polling.

is there any better way to achieve the same. ? ideally would like to be  get notified if the connection is lost/regained as what happens in the mobile application platforms like Android.

Thanks and Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Without checking the connection, I don't see it (it's kind of a Schrödinger problem)

Comment: Android can only inform if the WiFi has connection to the internet (again). It won't tell you anything about TCP connections. Or is checking network availability your actual goal?

Comment: @Fildor i agree....but probably on regaining/losing wifi connection i can try to check if to show message or retrying for tcp connection..at least i can reduce the time space like that...

Comment: I see, where you want to go... If I remember correctly, there was some possibility to get information about Network state via Runtime - Class... just looked, nope it was some other class ... maybe I can find it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html I think this was it.

Comment: @Fildor thanks a lot...i will check  and update if i can muster out something